# Android manually install OpenMobileApi

Tags: android, open-mobile-api

I'm developing an app with `OpenMobileApi`, I added the following on my manifest:

```
<uses-library
   android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"
   android:required="true" />
```

It installs successfully on a GS3, but on a nexus 3 it won't, mainly because of the `required=true`, because when I remove it, it installs fine.

Now I want to know if I can install the `OpenMobileApi` on the nexus3, I don't want to use an `external JAR` for it, is there a way I can do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found out the `OpenMobileApi` is not part of the `Android OS`, and it is present on a device by request from vendors and mobile operators.